# Unable to install app on new phone because "App is no longer available in the App Store"

Tags: iphone, itunes

I switched to an iPhone 8 Plus and found out that 2 paid apps cannot be downloaded anymore as they have been removed from the store.

I have copies of the app on several devices - the oldest device that still has this app is an iPhone 4.

I am having trouble transferring the app to my computer so that I can manually transfer it to my new device. Is there any way at all?

I've tried a few online suggestions but none works i.e. Transfer purchases, downgrade to iTunes 12 etc.

I paid for these 2 apps and would really appreciate help in getting them transferred over to my new device. Reaching out to the developer is not an option.

Comment: Are u signed into same Apple ID on both? If so, you should be able to download them from purchased.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work - I've tried on several devices - both apps either do not appear at all under purchased or if they do appear, cannot be downloaded i.e. when you click the cloud button, a message appears saying that the app cannot be downloaded because it has been removed. I've also tried looking under Purchases in iTunes on my desktop - they are not there.

Comment: If the developer removed the app from the App Store then you won't be able to download it again.  You would need to contact the developer to see if they offer a different app or different way to use the app, which you advised isn't an option.  This is under complete control of the developer and not the App Store.

Comment: I understand. But since I have copies of the app on older devices, is it possible for me to transfer it to my computer so that I can manually transfer it over to my new device?

Comment: If you take the risk and jailbreak both your iPhone 8+ and iPhone 4, you can dump an ipa from your iPhone 4 and install it on your iPhone 8+ (somehow). iOS 11 can be a problem since it doesn't support 32-bit sofrware and if the app on your iPhone 4 doesn't support 64-bit, then this won't work. iOS version isn't a problem, you can just downgrade to iOS 11.4b3 and jailbreak. This is a comment because it involves modifying iOS in an unintended way and it will cause you to lose your warranty.

Answer (score 1):

If the app is 32-bit it will not work on iOS 11.

If it *is* 64-bit but not in the AppStore you can:

- Find an .ipa file of the app and sideload it with Cydia Impactor
- Jailbreak both your iPhone 8 and 4. Then you can dump the .ipa file from your iPhone 4 (using something like iFunbox) and install it on your iPhone 8 (also using something like iFunbox or Cydia Impactor).

**Note:** Jailbreaking voids your warranty.